# Approach to adapt a smarty template according to specified flags

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am developing a small application which administers some data in a database. I am using the Smarty template engine to have everything working in MVC style and try to keep the code clean and structured as possible with the PHP scripts acting as the controllers and the smarty template as the view.

Now I wish to introduce the concept of permissions. For example one user can have rights to view and edit some of the data, while another could have other rights to view or edit different parts of the same data.

I am doing the checking in 2 places:
1. The controller itself, which checks whether the user has rights before performing the action. 
2. The view (smarty template), which checks whether the user has permissions and disables or changes to read only the respective control.

The latter part however is becoming a bit too verbose for my liking.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3" 
{if !$user->can(Permissions::EDIT_DESCRIPTION)}readonly{/if}>{$item['description']|default:''}</textarea>
```

Is there any better approach to this that is a bit more declarative or concise using Smarty to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about rather than leaking the whole of `$user` and its methods and constants into Smarty, make a custom modifier or two that checks a permission and does something useful based on it, e.g.:

A `check_access` modifier with the access type on the left (first param) and the true and false output on the right (second and third params):

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3" {'EDIT_DESCRIPTION'|check_access:'':'readonly'}>{$item['description']|default:''}</textarea>
```

Or even more specific, one which outputs the `readonly` attribute if it's necessary; I can't think of a good name though:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3" {'EDIT_DESCRIPTION'|readonly_if_no_access}>{$item['description']|default:''}</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes, your approach seems more declarative and along the lines of what I was looking for, rather than a bunch of `if` conditions that just make the template look like PHP code. So, if I understood you correctly, what the modifiers are doing are converting the type of permission required to the right presentation tag or attribute (for example adding `readonly` if necessary). I was also wondering if I can do it through a plugin instead, so that I could also combine access types if needed like `EDIT_DESCRIPTION | EDIT_EVERYTHING` (stupid example just to illustrate).

Comment: I suppose you could comma separate them and use `explode` in the callback to loop through them, e.g.: `{'EDIT_DESCRIPTION,EDIT_EVERYTHING'|check_access_any:'':'readonly'}` (I've called it `check_access_any`, as a `check_access_all` might also be useful occasionally).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "plugin"? A plugin in Smarty terms is any custom callback, be it a `{function}`, `|modifier`, `{block}{/block}` or any of the more exotic things like pre- and post-parsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By Plugin I meant Template Functions like this `{eightball}` example here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl I guess the term is used for any code enhancements you can make, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @jbx Right, I see. Functions like that are certainly more flexible, as they take named rather than positional parameters. They can't be used in `{if}` statements though, so have to be self-contained, and end up looking a bit more verbose (although you could argue that's a benefit in readability). The implementation is very similar: they just take an associative array of parameters as a single argument and you return what you want to output.